# Protect individual sites on Ubuntu/Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ubuntu

I need to set up a Apache server configuration for some client sites that run under the same Ubuntu 9.10 machine. All sites are allowed to run PHP, Python and Ruby on Rails. I do not control the source code of these sites and so I need to set up a filter in order to prevent one user to reach files on another users account.

If I run a script to list files in "/" from one account, I can browse some files and directories in the actual server root. I want to set the root for each account to /var/usersite.com/www/ instead so that listing files in "/" shows the files in the client's root.

How is this most easily configured?

Cheers!

/Christoffer

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at this wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot

If you just want to have files unreachable/unseen then why don't you just set the files to `700`?

Comment: `700` won't work because the webserver will need permissions to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a separate virtual server for each site, each with it's own DirectoryRoot such as /var/usersite.com/www/ Then, to make sure that only the user has access, I would require authentication to view the site. This can all be done in the httpd.conf file.